# undefined method `query_parameters' in Active Admin show/panel/table_for

Tags: activeadmin, has-many

I have something very similar working in another model, so there must be something minor that I'm overlooking.

I have a model Request that has_many RequestState(s), which in return has_one.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Request do
  show do |ad|
    ...
    panel "Request States" do
      table_for ad.request_states do
        column :id
        column :actor_id
        column :state
        column :created_at
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to load the page, I get:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::Requests#show
undefined method `query_parameters' for #<Request:0x000001062040c0>
```

and it's complaining about each of the "column" lines.

The underlying data seems fine since the following and similar work correctly from the rails console:

```
Request.find(37).request_states.pluck(:id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request is a reserved Class by Rails. I think you have to use something else class name.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html

But not sure, because it's namespaced...

Comment: It seems to work fine everywhere else and within that ActiveAdmin code, I'm able to do ad.request_states.count.  It's the column :id line that is unhappy, but I'll certainly investigate further whether the class name is conflicting.

Comment: I'm getting a bit lost trying to trace the the actual code called for "column" but I can see a lot of class stuff happening in there.  Even if there was a conflict for Request, however, I don't think that's what would be happening hear because the table_for is for models with type Request_State, which I don't believe is reserved?  For now, I'll just manually build my table since ad.request_states.each seems to work fine.

Comment: Ended up renaming because it seems other issues are cropping up in later Rails versions because of the conflict. That does fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in ActiveAdmin 1.0, and solved it without renaming my Rails model. I just renamed the resource within ActiveAdmin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Request, as: "BookRequest" do ...
```

This also forced me to rename my path helpers, e.g., `admin_request_path` became `admin_book_request_path` everywhere. Much less intrusive than renaming the Rails model though.

See https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#rename-the-resource

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue and, for me at least, it turned out to be the assignment of @request in a before_filter called in my ApplicationController:

```
      def newsletter
       @request = NewsletterRequest.new
      end
```

Changed the @request to @newsletter_request and avoided the collision.

Comment: Interesting, that definitely seems plausible in my case as well.  I'm not currently touching that code for a bit, but when I have a chance to follow up on this, I'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks for the lead.